# Python replace substring that has some variable component

Tags: python, split

I have the following string:

```
Billy got score of 2 and Tommy got score of 3
```

I want to split on `score of <some number>` so that I get

```
["Billy got","Tommy got"]
```

How can I do such a split in python? I tried

```
input.split("score of \d")
```

but that does not work. However, if I do

```
input.split("score of")
```

then I get

```
["Billy got "," 2 and Tommy got "," 3"]
```

**Update:**

Thanks for the answer to the original post. I have a follow up.

What if i want to replace `score of 2` with `score of 2$` ? meaning whenever i see `score of <some number>` just add a character `$` after the number

Comment: See [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) if you want to split with a regular expression.

Answer (score 3):

Well the reason why this does not work is because [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.split#str.split) expects a string as pattern: it is **not interpreted as a regex**.

You can however use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split):

```
import re

result = re.split(r'score of \d+(?: and )?',input)
```

You also should add the optional `(?: and )?` to remove the `and` combinator. Furthermore this answer uses `\d+` (with a `+`) such that multi-digit scores are also parsed correctly (like `"Tommy got score of 23"`).

In the interpreter:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> input="Billy got score of 2 and Tommy got score of 3"
>>> import re
>>> re.split(r'score of \d+(?:\s*and\s*)?',input)
['Billy got ', 'Tommy got ', '']
```

Comment: you probably wanted `[ and ]?` (square brackets), right?

Comment: @MSeifert: but `[]` is a character group, not an optional pattern.

Comment: haven't used regex in a while but `( and )` should match the `and` in a seperate substring. You need to make it part of the pattern, like `[( and )]` (does that work?)

Comment: @MSeifert: that's because it was a *capture group*, if you add `?:`, you make it a non-capture group

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. can i ask an update? what if i want to replace `score of 2` with `score of 2$` ? meaning whenever i see `score of <some number>` just add a character `$` after the number

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use `re.split` and split on the numbers alongside the preceding string:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "Billy got score of 2 and Tommy got score of 3"
>>> re.split(r' score of \d+', s)
['Billy got', ' and Tommy got', '']
```

You can also do some clean up with a list comprehension:

```
>>> [i.strip() for i in re.split(r' score of \d+', s) if i]
['Billy got', 'and Tommy got']
```

Answer (score 1):

Explanation on regular expression used here `(.+?) score of [0-9]+`

- Match anything with `score of` followed by some numbers
- `(.+?)` extract any thing before `score of` with a non-greedy search

Here is the code:

```
>>> import re
>>> sentence
'Billy got score of 2 and Tommy got score of 3'
>>> sentence.replace(' and ', ' ')
'Billy got score of 2 Tommy got score of 3'
>>> results = re.findall('(.+?) score of [0-9]+', sentence.replace(' and ', ' '))
>>> print results
['Billy got', ' Tommy got']
```